# Unable to import .gml MasterMap files

Tags: mapinfo, error, gml, os-mastermap

I'm new to MapInfo and am struggling to import .gml OS mastermap files.

The .gml is created by converting the .gz data that OS provide to .gml using the following batch file:

```
FOR /R "D:\path\to\files" %f IN (*.) DO REN "%f" *.gml
```

I have tried downloading the OS schema's that they provide on their website which doesn’t change the error message that I get which is as follows:

```
Unable to access "C:\filepath\ss10ne.gml file
```

Can anyone recommend a solution/alternative?

Comment: Are you using Universal Translator/FME Quick Translator to load the data into MapInfo Pro? What version of MapInfo Pro are you using?

Comment: Just using the Table - Import funtion. Version 12.5

Comment: Table, Import only support GML 2.1. Make sure the GML provided isn't GML3.x. If it is, you need to use Universal Ttranslator.